# .htaccess always showing 500 Internal server error codeingiter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

This is the .htaccess file which is my CI directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|[Javascript / CSS / Image root Folder name(s)]|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

And this is my apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But this is showing 500 internal error.

What is happening is there something wrong with what I have done?Please help

Comment: Does Apache write anything to the error log?

Comment: Were can I find the error log.Im new to this.

Comment: tried to remove the leading slash in front of index.php?

Comment: @Gafoor look for the `ErrorLog` directive in your configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Since your rule is not clearly shown I suspect either you have a syntax issue OR your rule is looping infinitely and causing 500.

Replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: You definitely need to look into your error.log for the reason of 500 in that case.

Comment: this is what is shown in error log  Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: That error means you haven't enabled `mod_rewrite` in your Apache config.